# Change the permission and ownership of a sub directory in centos

Tags: linux, centos, permissions, owner

I m having the following sub folder structure.

/public/trunk/src/common/site/

I want to change the ownership and permission for site and their sub directories alone.

How can i achieve that?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use below commands for changing permission & ownership for all files & sub directories:
    `chown user:group /public/trunk/src/common/site/ -R`

&  `chmod 664  /public/trunk/src/common/site/ -R`

If you want to skip the files & want to apply only on directories

`find /public/trunk/src/common/site/ -type d -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 775`